# How to get profile properties for users

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, office-365

I am creating one javascript file to bring all users emails and birthdates using JSOM.

```
var targetUser = elm; // elm is my user name eg:i:0#.f|membership|xyzuser@mydomain.com 
    // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Specify the properties to retrieve and target user for the 
    // UserProfilePropertiesForUser object.
    var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "Department","WorkEmail"];
    var userProfilePropertiesForUser = 
        new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
            clientContext,
            targetUser,
            profilePropertyNames);

    // Get user profile properties for the target user.
    // To get the value for only one user profile property, use the
    // getUserProfilePropertyFor method.
    userProfileProperties =(peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(
        userProfilePropertiesForUser));

    // Load the UserProfilePropertiesForUser object and send the request.
    clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);       
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnQuerySuccess, OnQueryFail);

//success function
function OnQuerySuccess(data){
                console.log(data);

}
```

It is going to `OnQuerySuccess` method. If I log the data object it is showing string like 
`SP.ClientRequest {$$d_$3C_0: function, $16_0: Array[4], $1L_0: Object, $0_0: SP.ClientContext, $P_0: SP.ClientQueryInternal…}`
I unable to know how to iterate through this collection. Even I try to implement the following said solutions.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104(v=office.15).aspx
http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

I am attaching image how that data object is looking.
[image]

When I log the user profile properties I am getting value in console like below
[image]

Comment: Can you add the success handler?

Comment: Yes added... in success handler only I am getting this output.

Comment: Try accessing `userProfileProperties` within your success handler.

Comment: Sorry @wjervis, I didn't get you

Comment: Your success handler is using `data`.  Remove the parameter, and instead just log `userProfileProperties`, and see what values are in it, as in Aveenav's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
//success function
    function OnQuerySuccess(data){
     window.console && console.log(userProfileProperties);
     window.console && console.log('Success');
     var prefName= "Preferred Name: " + userProfileProperties[0];
     window.console && console.log(prefName);     

     var dept = "Department: " + userProfileProperties[1];
     window.console && console.log(dept);     

     var email = "Email: " + userProfileProperties[2];
     window.console && console.log(email);      
    }
```

You can comment out this line

```
//clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
```

Comment: Even i tried this solution also. But no use. I have total 5 user profiles. When I log the userProfilePoperties it is giving 4 empty arrays and one array with only "PreferredName" value, other values like "SPS-Birthday", "PictureURL" etc not coming in the output.

Comment: You'd need to include properties SPS-Birthday and PictureURL to your array 
var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "Department","WorkEmail", "SPS-Birthday", "PictureURL"];

If you're still unsuccessful at retrieving properties with CSOM, try the rest API: _api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties

Answer (score 0):

The following example works for me

```
var targetUser = 'i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'; 
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);

var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "Department","WorkEmail"];
var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
            context,
            targetUser,
            profilePropertyNames);
var userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

context.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

context.executeQueryAsync(
function(){
    //print user profile properties
    userProfileProperties.forEach(function(val){
        console.log(val);
    });
}, 
function(sender,args){
   console.log(args.get_message());    
});
```